# How do I combine these lines into one line of R code?

Tags: r

How would I format these lines of code to be able to fit into one line of code?

```
TotalHoursAsleep <- sleep_data$TotalMinutesAsleep/60
TotalHoursAsleep <- as.double(TotalHoursAsleep)
sleep_data$TotalHoursAsleep <- TotalHoursAsleep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```r
sleep_data$TotalHoursAsleep <- sleep_data$TotalMinutesAsleep / 60
```

You don't need `as.double` at all. Even if the total minutes asleep is an integer variable and each member is divisible by 60, the act of dividing it by 60 automatically converts it to a `double`. This is true even if you specify that the 60 is an integer by doing `60L`

```r
x <- c(60L, 120L, 180L)
typeof(x)
#> [1] "integer"

y <- 60L
typeof(y)
#> [1] "integer"

z <- x / y
typeof(z)
#> [1] "double"
```